# How can I check if mms connection is alive?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I'm trying to check whether some mms links are alive or broken. I tried using netconnection however it didn't work, I got error.

**EDIT:**
Here's the code I tried:

```
    // Inside function
    ShowCheckConnectionPopup();

    if (connection_combobox.selectedIndex == 0) {
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://" + addressStr));
    } else if (connection_combobox.selectedIndex == 1) {
        rtmpVurl = "rtmp://" + rtmpVurl;
        rtmp_test = new RTMP_test();
        addChild(rtmp_test);
        rtmp_test.init(rtmpSid, rtmpVurl);
        rtmp_test.addEventListener(CustomEvent2.PASS_PARAMS, onTestProcessed);
        /*
        rtmp_player.vid.x = 100;
        rtmp_player.vid.y = 100;
        */
    } else if (connection_combobox.selectedIndex == 2) {
        addressStr = "mms://" + addressStr;
        createRtmpConnection(addressStr);
    }
}

var _ncConnection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
// create a new net connection, add event listener and connect
// to null because we don’t have a media server
_ncConnection = new NetConnection();
_ncConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
_ncConnection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
_ncConnection.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,errorHandler);
_ncConnection.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
// _ncConnection.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,metaHandler);

function createRtmpConnection(s:String) {
    rtmpTimeoutTimer.reset();
    rtmpTimeoutTimer.start();
    _ncConnection.connect(s);
}
```

> ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.     at
>   flash.net::NetConnection/connect()    at
>   Untitled_02_02_fla::MainTimeline/createRtmpConnection()[Untitled_02_02_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:741]
>     at
>   Untitled_02_02_fla::MainTimeline/onPopupOkBtnClick()[Untitled_02_02_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:568]*
>
> Line 741: _ncConnection.connect(s);
>
> Line 568: createRtmpConnection(addressStr);

Comment: Post the code you tried along with the error you mentioned.

Comment: Where is `addressStr` defined?

Comment: I posted a part of that function. I posted full function here: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/558545/

Comment: Potentially `address_ta.text` is not a valid value.